# Calcular a soma de 02 campos automaticamente

Tags: jquery

Tenho os  seguintes campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O **Nº de Alunos** vem do banco de dados e estou armazenando em um campo oculto:

```
<input type="hidden" name="NumAlunos" id="numAlunos" value="<?php echo $visualizar->NumAlunos; ?>" class="form-control">
```

Como eu faria para multiplicar esse campo com o valor unitário e preencher o campo da Receita?

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="valorDesconto">Valor Unitário:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #FAFAFA">
                    <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
                  </div>
                    <input type="text" name="ValorUnitario" class="form-control pull-right" id="valor" maxlength="10">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="valorDesconto">Receita:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #FAFAFA">
                    <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
                  </div>
                    <input type="text" name="ValorReceita" class="form-control pull-right" id="valorReceita" maxlength="10">
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Depende como você quer... ao digitar, ao sair do campo, apenas quando tiver mudanças no campo e assim vai.

Comment: `$("#valorReceita").val( Number($("#NumAlunos").val()) * Number($("#ValorUnitario").val()) )`

Comment: Olá Everson. Será ao sair do campo do Valor Unitário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando Jquery:

Use a função Blur, essa função é ativada ao sair do input selecionado..

```
$("#valor").blur(function(){
  var receita = $("#numAlunos").val() * $(this).val(); 
  $("#valorReceita").val(receita);
});
```

Isto deve funcionar

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo. Funcionou!